# Delete a MySQL selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to delete my MySQL selection.

Here is my MySQL selection request:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Items 
 WHERE id_user=1 
 ORDER 
    BY id_user 
 LIMIT 2,1
```

With this working request, I select the third item on my table which has as `id_user`: 1.

Now, I would like to delete the item that has been selected by my request.

I am looking for a same meaning request which would look like this :

```
DELETE FROM Items (
   SELECT * FROM Items WHERE id_user=1 ORDER BY id_user LIMIT 2,1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that there is an issue with your query. You are *filtering* on a unique value of `id_user` and *sorting* on the same column. As all records in the resultset will have the same `id_user`, the actual order of the resultset is undefined, and we cannot reliably tell which record comes third.

Assuming that you have another column to disanbiguate the resultset (ie some value that is unique amongst each group of records having the same `id_user`), say `id`, here is a solution to your question, that uses a self-join with `ROW_NUMBER()` to locate the third record in each group.

```
DELETE i
FROM items i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        id_user, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM items
) c ON c.id = i.id AND c.id_user = i.id_user AND c.rn = 3
WHERE i.id_user=1 ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cZ9TSaGZPSN6XzDGtRpYBU/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the definition of your table. I guess it has a primary key column called `id`.

In that case you can use this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE doomed_ids 
    SELECT id FROM Items WHERE id_user = 1 ORDER BY id_user LIMIT 2,1;
DELETE FROM Items
      WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM doomed_ids);
DROP TABLE doomed_ids;
```

It's a pain in the neck, but it works around the limitation of MySQL and MariaDB disallowing `LIMIT`s in `... IN (SELECT ...)` clauses.

Comment: (The limitation is the offset)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select query to create a derived table and join it back to your main table to determine which record(s) to delete. Derived tables can use the `limit` clause.

Assuming that the PK is called `id`, the query would look as follows:

```
delete i from items i
inner join (SELECT id FROM Items 
            WHERE id_user=1 
            ORDER BY id_user LIMIT 2,1) i2 on i.id=i2.id
```

You need to substitute your PK in place of `id`. If you have a multi-column PK, then you need to select all the PK fields in the derived table and join on all of them.

Comment: (Offset clause)